# Как запомнить предыдущий элемент на jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Делаю клик по рандомному блоку функцией:

```
function randomChange() {

    var numItems = $('.tablebox').length;
    var randomBlock = getRandomArbitary(2, numItems - 2);

    $(".tablebox:eq(" + randomBlock + ")").click();
}
```

Нужно чтобы скрывало предыдущий элемент при клике на новый. Как можно запоминать индекс предыдущего элемент?

Comment: Будет лучше, если вы предоставите минимальный рабочий пример, где будет видно, что скрывается, а что нет!

Comment: @IgorTkachuk, ничего не скрывается, просто пытаюсь понять как в рандоме получить предыдущее число рандома

Answer (score 1):

разобрался,

```
var lastindex = Number; //Глобальная переменная индекса

    function randomChange(index) {
    lastindex = randomBlock;
    $(".tablebox:eq(" + index + ")").hide();
    }
```

и сама функция

```
randomChange(lastindex);
```